# Dictionaries declared inside function

Tags: python, dictionary

Have searched around but unable to find a solution to this really basic question I was hoping someone could help enlighten me on (apologies if I have missed it somewhere!) Why must the dictionary `count_letters` below be declared within the function as opposed to outside?

In the first version, I am able to correctly declare `address_count`, but in the second incorrect version, I am unable to create `address_count` as it returns `nonetype object of builtins module" error`. Any knowledge would be greatly appreciated!

**Correct Solution**

```
 def counter (input_string):
    count_letters = {}
    for letter in input_string:
        if letter in count_letters:
                count_letters[letter] += 1
        else:
            count_letters[letter] = 1
    return count_letters

    address_count = counter(address)
```

**Incorrect Solution**

```
count_letters = {}

def counter(input_string):
    for letter in input_string: 
        if letter in alphabet: 
            if letter in count_letters:
                count_letters[letter] += 1
            else: 
                count_letters[letter] = 1

address_count = count_letters
```

Comment: You are missing the `return` statement from the **incorrect solution** of yours

Comment: You never actually called `counter()`, so nothing in that function matters.

Comment: thank you!! i'm new to stack overflow - should i now delete this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "incorrect" solution just works if you call the function and remove the unreferenced alphabet variable

```
count_letters = {}

def counter(input_string):
    for letter in input_string: 
        if letter in count_letters:
            count_letters[letter] += 1
        else: 
            count_letters[letter] = 1

counter("test")
print(count_letters)
```